# Saving multiple figures in a specific folder in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I have 13 figures named like figure(1), figure(2)... so on. 
I want to save all the figure at once in a specific folder D:\figures. I tried this.. What went wrong?

```
for i=1:1:13
 saveas(figure(1),fullfile('D:\figures\',['figure' num2str(1) '.jpeg']));
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using your loop-variable inside your loop...
Replace your `1` with `i`:

```
for i=1:1:13
 saveas(figure(i),fullfile('D:\figures\',['figure' num2str(i) '.jpeg']));
end
```